# How to use XmlTextWriter in windows8 Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm creating a windows store application in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8. I need to use the `XmlTextWriter` to write my output. I included the namespace

```
using System.Xml;
```

But the class is still not found. Can someone tell me how to use the `XmlTextWriter` in a Windows 8 Metro application?

Comment: Well what happened with what you've tried? (Note that you'll need `u` rather than `U` - C# is case-sensitive.)

Comment: Even in the full .NET framework you should not use the XmlTextWriter class. You should **always** use the `XmlWriter.Create` factory methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm Creating an windows store application in Visual studio 2012 in
>   windows 8. I need to use the XmlTextWriter to write the output.

You cannot use XmlTextWriter within a Windows Store application.  You must use the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) class instead.  In the future if a class does not list itself as supporting .NET for Windows Store apps then it cannot be used within an application being targeted to the Windows Store.

Since XmlWriter is an abstract class it basically means you will have to recreate the `XmlTextWriter` class.